# Why are the Millennium Falcon and other civilian vessels allowed to have ship-mounted weapons?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, laws, millennium-falcon, han-solo

First things first, let's just pretend the hyperspace ramming in the Last Jedi didn't happen, because hyperspace ramming means every FTL-capable vessel in the galaxy is a deadly weapon capable of destroying star destroyers, making this thread irrelevant.

Okay, so according to Wookieepedia, Han Solo won the Millennium Falcon [gambling with Lando Calrissian](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo#Early_life). This explains how he was able to afford the ship. The Falcon is a [YT-1300 Corellian Light freighter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/YT-1300_light_freighter). Wookieepedia defines freighters as such:

> A freighter, cargo ship, or barge was a kind of spacecraft used for
>   hauling cargo from one place to another. Although light freighters
>   could usually hold their own in combat against other fighter craft,
>   larger vessels tended to be less capable. These large freighters could
>   be easy targets considering their large size, slow speed, and weak
>   armament. For this reason most heavy freighters required escorts when
>   navigating more dangerous regions of the galaxy.

This is troubling; does this mean civilians are allowed to pilot spacecraft mounted with weapons capable of destroying other vessels? Spaceships can't be cheap, and I'm assuming Han has some sort of title and registration for the falcon, but in the real world most vehicles much bigger than an RV are owned by organizations, and in the case of naval vessels owned by shipping companies, merchant marines, or part of a country's fleet. With that comes all sorts of regulations, licensing fees, ID numbers, permits...

So what is Han Solo's official job title? We all know he's a smuggler, but that implies that his "official" job is something like cargo shipper or merchant. Or does he fly under the radar at all times, running from every authority he sees? What about other private vessels? Wookieepedia makes it clear that other freighters are allowed to have weapons mounted on their ships.

In the past during wartime private vessels were temporarily allowed to be mounted with weapons ([relevant Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensively_equipped_merchant_ship)), but that was an exceptional time (although granted the original trilogy does take many cues from WWII). Yes, armed guards with small arms are allowed, though expensive ([Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/1oz6wc/why_cant_cargo_freight_ships_carry_weapons_to/), [The Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/sponsored/culture/captain-phillips-film/10367534/security-against-pirate-attacks.html))... but ship-mounted weapons are a different story ([Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090415080807AAkEtH0&guccounter=1), [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-international-cargo-ships-carry-weapons)). but what is the rationalization for a private spaceship like the Millennium Falcon being outfitted with weaponry capable of shooting down a pursuing fleet of Imperial Tie Fighters (the equivalent of fighter jets attacking a merchant freighter)? This "freighter" took out a *Death Star* for crying out loud.

My guess is it's allowed because of space pirates or the difficulty of maintaining law in the vast reaches of space, but then again, you'd think the Empire wouldn't allow much leeway considering their greatest threat is a massive covert rebellion and all. It seems like it would make more sense for freighters to be escorted or dangerous areas patrolled by the Empire.

I'm writing a sci-fi story of my own so it would be nice to know if there is a decent explanation other than "because it's cool." Example from sci-fi works other than Star Wars are welcome as well.

Comment: Why should we pretend that some element of a story didn't happen?

Comment: @Adamant Oh, from the Last Jedi. Because Hyperspace ramming means every FTL-capable vessel in the galaxy is a deadly weapon capable of destroying star destroyers, making this thread irrelevant. I edited the post.

Comment: It sounds like you’ve answered your own question there?

Comment: @Adamant not if we ignore the sequels to the original trilogy. I don't want this thread to devolve into a hyperspace ramming debate so let's stick to why civilian vessels are allowed to have ship-mounted weapons.

Comment: There are multiple conflicting *Star Wars* continuities.  Some make more sense than others.  This question restricts itself to those versions on the *Star Wars* universe that at least try to make sense.

Comment: My understanding from all my readings : different planets, different laws. Some of them allow weapons, other don't. Generally people are allowed to have weapons. A lot of places are dangerous, as there are a lot of criminals, pirates and smugglers. And if weapons are not allowed, corruption is the key for authorities to not see them.

Comment: If we bring real world analogies, SW is like the age of high seas piracy. If pirates are recognized as a universal threat, then a cargo ship either has to be armed enough to fight back the pirates, or be accompanied by an armed fleet. Most ships of the age were allowed to carry cannons powerful enough to disable any ship in range (by knocking down the main mast). Also, regulation on ownership were a bit relaxed at those times.

Comment: Also, the Galaxy far far away is a big place. Who's gonna check every single ship out there?

Comment: There was the right to keep and bear (and mount) arms?

Comment: FWIW "hyperspace ramming" is similar to driving a car into people in our times and there's no law stopping people driving except a license which is similar to Star Wars so I don't see how that point is relevant.

Comment: Yeah, ramming is a real world thing that is also very effective in the real world, *in a sense*, and yet we still use weapons instead of ramming for very good reasons. Militarily, ramming is not usually a viable tactic because the value of the ramming vehicle and its crew must be far less than the value of the target and its crew for it to even be a possible viable tactic. Then there's the morale issue. All that aside, both issues were addressed by the Japanese air force in WWII which had a tactic of ramming naval vessels with inexpensive airplanes. And yet we still prefer weapons.

Comment: Pretending hyper-space ramming doesn't exist turns this into a "what if" question, which is unfortunate and unnecessary, since there's a valid answer regardless. You're forgetting that people typically prefer not dying, tend to be averse to blowing up their rather expensive ships, and countermeasures exist (Interdictor gravity wells, for example). Nuclear bombs have not made the need for conventional weaponry obsolete. All this to say, you're better off leaving that part out, and any off topic discussion can be handled by the rules meant to handle such.

Comment: @Mwr247 - I suspect the get-out will be that most ships lack the capacity to manually go into hyperspace, that small ships performing a "holdo-jump" would simply be obliterated by standard shields and that the calculations required are extremely hard to perform. Holdo basically got lucky that the Supremacy was exactly between her and the target destination.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Thanks Buzz. Even though I discouraged talking about Hyperspace ramming, some of you made valid points. @Neow: Ah gotcha. I was thinking the Empire had like, absolute law over all the planets. So, they're more like Rome letting planets retain some autonomy. Loki: that was sort of my thought as well. TimSparrow: I like the analogy to the age of high seas piracy and more lax laws. I guess any vehicle without defense would be easily taken by space pirates. I (facetiously) wish Mad Max style raiders existed so I could justify mounting a machine gun on my car.

Comment: The ramming would be incredibly powerful. Actually infinitely powerful., One of the problems with FTL is that a vessel travelling the speed of light impacts with infinite kinetic energy. A speck of sand becomes a bomb with the power of the universe. Now, of course, "infinite energy" can't exist, and neither can FTL. And even was possible on its own terms, it would still require infinite energy to get that fast. And we bend that rule at our peril if we care about realistic consequences.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [Star Wars Official Fact File #51](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_51), transport ships and licensed freighters like the Millennium Falcon were permitted to carry a certain amount of low-energy weaponry, presumably for basic self-defence from pirates and to help navigate systems with natural obstructions such as asteroids.

Turbolasers and other high-powered weapons were illegal under Imperial law but ships on the Outer Rim (where those laws hold little sway) often toted them anyway.

> *"Out on the lawless fringes of the known galaxy, transport ships and
>   independent freighters often sported heavier laser cannon armaments
>   than Imperial-era legislatures permitted."*

Comment: Also, in the Incredible Cross Sections, the quad-lasers that the Falcon had were considered illegal too.

Comment: Han admits he made modifications to the ship.

Comment: A quick mention: One of the earliest Star Wars novels, *Han Solo at Star's End* by Brian Daley, published in 1979 (and set before the original movie), addressed this subject. In one scene, the "Security Police" (cops in one sector of the Galaxy) inform Han Solo that regulations have been tightened up, and his ship seems to be lacking the correct permits, etc., for the firepower, extra defensive shielding, long-range sensor gear, etc., that's obviously been added to his ship to make it much more of a "firecracker" than a privately owned freighter is supposed to be.

Comment: Valorum, @Lorendiac, CBredlow, and SiXandSeven8ths: thanks! These were just the answers I was looking for. So the Empire did _indeed_ have laws pertaining to legal private ownership of ship-mounted weapons... just not to the radical degree of the Millennium Falcon. So those were the "[special modifications](https://youtu.be/i1WkXxWoGiI)" he was referring to...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, they are allowed to have lower-power weapons, but not higher power weapons, like the *Falcon*'s quad cannons or turbolasers. So the *Millenium Falcon* is equipped with illegal military-grade weaponry, but Han doesn't care because a) he's Han Solo and b) he's based on Tatooine, where the Empire really doesn't have much presence. Plus, the *Falcon* is a Corellian YT-1300 freighter, which is a very fast ship, allowing it to outrun ships in realspace and all ships move at the same speed through hyperspace, so Han has some ground to not worry too much about his illegal weaponry (also, the people who Han associates with aren't the kind of people who *could* report him to the Empire without risking their own skins). And as for it destroying the DS-II Battle Station, a person with a DC-15A assault rifle (the standard issue rifle for Clone Troopers) or even an E-11 blaster could have destroyed it if they had the chance to get into that kind of a position in the superstructure of the battle station because the main reactor was exposed. It only needed a sufficient amount of energy input to overload the reactor to destroy the DS-II battle station.